# Django mysql query only returns first column

Tags: python, django

I have a small test app i am working on and at the moment no matter what i do query wise the object only ever returns the first field from the model not the matching row data? if it print the query i get the correct mysql results so unsure what i am doing wrong here?

Model:

```
class NotesPost(models.Model):
    noteUrl = models.CharField(default='', max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    notePostDate = models.CharField(default='', max_length=40)
    noteName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    noteMessage = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.noteUrl
```

Now i do the following in shell

```
from testnotes.models import NotesPost
test = NotesPost.objects.filter(noteUrl='onjgRZBYTG')
```

However what i receive is:

```
>>> test
<NotesPost: onjgRZBYTG>
>>> print(test.query)
```

The result i get back (sorted for this post)

```
SELECT 
`notespost`.`id`, 
`notespost`.`noteUrl`, 
`notespost`.`notePostDate`, 
`notespost`.`noteName`, 
`notespost`.`noteMessage` 
FROM 
    `notespost` 
WHERE 
    `notespost`.`publicUrl` = 'onjgRZBYTG'
```

Which in the db is correct and returns the entire row as expected?
So at the moment i am unsure why i am only receiving the first column of the query object and not the whole row, as i would like to update the row and present data from the row.

Many thanks

Comment: Whay you mean by first column? Your `SELECT` contain all columns of the table.

Comment: @Charnel not it really is just the first db column <QuerySet [< NotesPost: onjgRZBYTG>]>
>>> for i in test:
...     print(i)
... 
onjgRZBYTG
>>>

Comment: You don't receive the first item. It just *prints* the first item. But you can acess any attribute, like `test.noteMessage`.

Comment: @Psymon25: that is because it is a `QuerySet`, not an object, you should use `.get(..)` or `.first(..)`, etc. to obtain an object: a `QuerySet` is a *collection* of items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So at the moment i am unsure why i am only receiving the first column of the query object and not the whole row.

You **do not** receive only the first column. It simply *prints* the first column. Why? Because you instructed that in your `__str__` implementation:

```
class NotesPost(models.Model):
    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return self.noteUrl
```

By default for a model, the `__repr__` is implemented to return `<ModelName: %s>` with `%s` the result of the `str(object)` call.

But that does *not* mean that the object itself only contains that specific data. You can for example fetch another attribute with:

```
test[0].noteMessage
```

Here your `test` however is a `QuerySet` of `NotesPost` objects, so a *collection*. You can use functions like [**`.get(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get),  [**`.first(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first), and  [**`.last(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#last) to obtain model *objects*.

Comment: ok i was having issues during my learning between filter, get, all i re-started and cleared the django cache and using your suggestion its all working - feel a tad silly now ;)